# Scala - Map A Tuple To A Map of Maps?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a list of tuples:

```
val t = List( (1,2,1.0), (1,3,2.0), (1,2,1.1) )
```

I want to create a map with `t._1` as the key, and as the value a map with `t._2` as the key and the sum of `t._3` as the value.

```
val m = Map( (1-> Map((2 -> 2.1), (3 -> 2.0)) )
```

How can I do this in Scala?

I'd like to accomplish this with pure Scala as opposed to a library, but if a library such as scalaz etc. is (in my completely subjective opinion) a nicer looking solution, I would accept that answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are into one-liners then you might like this:

```
val t = List( (1,2,1.0), (1,3,2.0), (1,2,1.1) )
t.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._3).sum))
```

Result is:

```
Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 2.1, 3 -> 2.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
t.groupBy(_._1).map {
    case (outerKey, outerList) =>
        outerKey -> outerList.groupBy(_._2).map {
            case (innerKey, innerList) =>
                innerKey -> innerList.map(_._3).sum
        }
}
```

yields:

```
Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 2.1, 3 -> 2.0))
```